Power Automate Group & Count Items
Given an output like this one, obtained from Microsoft Graph.
[
        {
            "userPrincipalName": "user@contoso.com",
            "companyName": "CONTOSO"
        },
        {
            "userPrincipalName": "user2@spiceworks.com",
            "companyName": "SPICEWORKS"
        },
        {
            "userPrincipalName": "user3@contoso.com",
            "companyName": "CONTOSO"
        },
        {...}
]

Im not able to group the output by companyName in order to count them.
The idea is to obtain total number of occurrences per companyName. For example, CONTOSO = 2, SPICEWORKS = 1.
Considerations:
I’m using Premium Power Automate on the web, where data is being collected within a "for each" loop. This is necessary because the task needs to be executed for multiple IDs, which serve as parameters for the Graph API call. We don't know the amount of different companies coming from the output, as they can be more than 2.

Update:
This is the current state:
I gather all the CompanyNames, and then union with its self to remove all the duplicates. From that output I generate and XML file.
I'm able to count that XML file by using xpath.
Expression used on Xpather:
count(/root/array[normalize-space(companyName)="CONTOSO"])

Expression adapted for Power Automate
xpath(outputs('Create_XML'), concat('count(/root/array[normalize-space(companyName)="',item(),'"])'))

But when flow is run, this is the error I get:

The execution of template action 'Final_Output' failed: The evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression '{
"companyName": "@item()",
"Total": "@xpath(outputs('Create_XML'), concat('count(/root/array[normalize-space(companyName)="',item(),'"])'))"
}' failed: 'The template language function 'xpath' parameters are invalid: the 'xpath' parameter must be a supported, well formed XPath expression. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xpath for usage details.'.

Credits to Untethered 365

Use the Expert operation in the Advanced Data Operations connector.  Makes it easier and less verbose for your flow when you can apply SQL to your JSON data.
For the parameters ...
Query String
SELECT companyName, Count(*) AS Count
FROM [Data]
GROUP BY companyName

Data
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "userPrincipalName": "user@contoso.com",
      "companyName": "CONTOSO"
    },
    {
      "userPrincipalName": "user2@spiceworks.com",
      "companyName": "SPICEWORKS"
    },
    {
      "userPrincipalName": "user3@contoso.com",
      "companyName": "CONTOSO"
    }
  ]
}

Flow

Result

It's not free but it's affordable, has a heap of more advanced tooling to convert and transform data AND will cut down the development effort.
The alternative is a lot of looping and counting.

Thank you for the great answer! I’d prefer to stick to using the default tools for now. I’ve posted an update, and it's almost working just integrated tools.
